# Member Import Alternative

Tags: members, import, xml, csv

I know you can import members by using the built in import function, but that uses XML. Who keeps their data in XML...?
There's the CSV to XML converter, but its hardly client-friendly.

Are there any alternative methods to import members?

A client of mine takes down member details manually at their store, and they want to upload them in bulk on a semi-regular basis.
Ideally I'd like the client to just have to upload a CSV (in a format we can define).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been working on a module to import members from CSV files. You can download it here:

https://bitbucket.org/ajweaver/ajw_import_members

If you are familiar with [DataGrab](http://brandnewbox.co.uk/products/details/datagrab) it is very similar so you define the data source, map data fields to member fields and then run the import. You can also save imports and re-run them again later.

It is working fine on the handful of sites that are using it, but consider it "beta" software for now and take a backup before you try using it!

Answer (score 6):

I suggest moving the member info over to channel entries with a third party add-on like [Profile:Edit](http://mightybigrobot.com/products/detail/profile-edit) or [Zoo Visitor](http://ee-zoo.com/add-ons/visitor/). This opens member data and gives you a ton of power and flexibility you normally get with channel entries and custom fields. You could then use [DataGrab](http://brandnewbox.co.uk/products/details/datagrab) to setup and configure a member import to automatically load a .csv file from a given url and re-run that import weekly or however often as needed.

Comment: Is it difficult to change from regular membership to one of those channel based modules? I have a lot of members on the site already.

Comment: I can't speak for Zoo Visitor, but Profile:Edit has a utility to create profile entries for existing members who do not already have a profile entry. It also transfers custom member fields too!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. While moving to a channel based solution is probably a good idea, I've already got so much set up on this site in terms of membership. I'm using Solspace User to manage the front-end aspects. Switching would be more work than the budget/timeframe allows for. Andrew mentioned his member import module, judging by DataGrab I'd have to say that it'll be a perfect solution.